# Kendo with Angular2: Implementing pagination with all, getting issue with NaN in dropdwown pager

Tags: pagination, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to implement pagination with Kendo Angular 2. Pagination works fine if its number, but if it includes 'all' also along with numbers, it breaks. I am getting NaN also along with other page sizes. I am checking NaN in my method and I am assigning a number if its a NaN.Below is my sample solution.

```
<kendo-grid  [data]="gridData"    [pageable]= "{
            pageSizes: ['all',100, 200, 300, 400, 500],
            numeric: false
          }"              
          (pageChange)="pageChange($event)" (remove)="removeHandler($event)">
```

Typescript File

```
 protected pageChange({ skip, take }: PageChangeEvent): void {
     this.skip = skip;
     if(isNaN(take))
     {
     this.pageSize = 100;
     }
     else
     {
     this.pageSize = take;
     }
       this.gridData = {
         data: this.gridData.slice(this.skip, this.skip + this.pageSize),
         total: this.gridData.length
       };
```